# A problem in modular roots

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, computational-complexity, computational-number-theory

We have three mutually coprime integers $r,t,M$ where $M\asymp K^{\frac12-2\epsilon}$ and $r,t\asymp K^{\frac14+\epsilon}$ holds with some fixed $\epsilon>0$ and $K>0$ is a large parameter. Assume $M^2-4rt$ is a prime if need be.

> 1. What is the largest integer $T$ (preferably prime) with $$2\sqrt{rt}+M\equiv0\bmod T?$$
> 2. Is there a fast method to find the largest $T$ allowable and can it be much larger than $K$ (preferably order $\Omega(K^\alpha)$ at arbitrary $\alpha\geq1$)?

Preferably the method should be in $e^{o(\log K)}$ time. Ideally it should be $O(polylog(K))$.

> 3. Also for every possible can $\zeta_r,\zeta_t\asymp T^{\frac12+\beta}$ hold where $\zeta_r^2\equiv r\bmod T$ and $\zeta_t^2\equiv t\bmod T$ while $\beta>0$ is very small and is fixed?

Comment: Is there $T\gg M^2+4rt$ here?

Comment: Is your first sentence a question or a statement? It sounds like a statement (a condition) but it ends with a question mark. If it is a question, it should read "Do we have three mutually etc." In Question 2 which integer do you ask about: $r$ or $t$ or $M$ or $T$? Please try to ask more clearly.

Comment: Corrected. In 2. I am trying to find largest $T$ possible and it appears $M^2-4rt$ will work however I want something much larger of order $K^2$.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by the congruence, since $\sqrt{rt}$ is not an integer. Note also that, in analytic number theory, the symbol $\gg$ means "larger than a positive constant times". So $K\gg 0$ makes little sense (it is equivalent to $K>0$); you probably meant that $K$ is a large parameter. Finally, I inserted $T$ in the first question.

Comment: @GHfromMO I am just saying $2\zeta+M\equiv0\bmod T$ and $\zeta^2\equiv rt\bmod T$. Corrected $\gg$.

Comment: If $T$ is odd, your condition is equivalent to (since you seem to allow choosing which square root we take) $T\mid M^2-4rt$. If $T$ is even, dividing by $2$ this seems to be equivalent to $T/2\mid M^2/4-rt$. Am I missing anything or does this immediately let one see what the largest $T$ will be?

Comment: @Wojowu Size bounds seems to imply $M^2-4rt$ is largest if it needs to be prime. If I have quadratically larger it might have utility.

Comment: @Turbo I don't see how your size conditions are remotely relevant. If you require T to be prime, you just get that the largest such T is the largest prime factor of $M^2-4rt$.

Comment: Ninth version today, not to mention four self-deletions & undeletions.

Comment: The fact that $T$ divides $M^2-4rt$ prohibits *any* higher than that. And the size condition, again, has nothing to do with it.